# Can't find gridview by id

Tags: android, gridview

My code cant find the GridView with `android:id="@+id/grid"`

to find the gridview i use: `GridView grid = (GridView) ViewAlbum.this.findViewById(R.id.grid);`

In a `ASyncTask` i have to make an `adapter` out of a `mysql` table. `Mysql` is working fine, but an error occurrs when i'm trying to find the `gridview`.

Here is the `onPostExecute` part:

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            // dismiss dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();      
            // Add adapter to the list
            ViewAlbumAdapter adapter = new ViewAlbumAdapter(ViewAlbum.this, photoList);
            GridView grid = (GridView) ViewAlbum.this.findViewById(com.example.whs.R.id.grid);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                // do something
                }
            });
        }
```

and the gridview:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ViewAlbum" >

    <GridView android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the log for the errors:

```
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at com.example.whs.ViewAlbum$LoadAllItems.onPostExecute(ViewAlbum.java:139)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at com.example.whs.ViewAlbum$LoadAllItems.onPostExecute(ViewAlbum.java:1)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-02 18:07:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(16432):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Provide more detail on what is your problem, what goes wrong and stack trace

Comment: Where is the GridView on the code that you have posted ?

Comment: in activity_view_album.xml i'v updated the code above

Comment: btw, ive added the wrong code for the `onPostExecute()`. updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GridView grid = (GridView) ViewAlbum.this.findViewById(com.example.whs.R.id.grid);
```

You won't get the View this way.

If your async task is inner class in the same activity, then call get like this

```
GridView grid = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(com.example.whs.R.id.grid);
```

If your Async Task is in separate class, you need to inflate the view to get access to your gridview

Comment: asynctask is a subclass of ViewAlbum.class, but getActivity() is marked as an undefined method

Comment: You can access the views declared globally in your activity in your async task post execute....Try to do like this 1. declare gridView as global variable GridView grid; in your activity and in your Activity OnCreate method try to get the view like this GridView grid = (GridView)findViewById(com.example.whs.R.id.grid);

Comment: Also try like this GridView grid = (GridView)findViewById(com.example.whs.R.id.grid);  in your post execute

Comment: still `grid.setAdapter(adapter)` is wrong, and i'm sure that he can't find the `grid`

Comment: @Stumpje what do you meant by wrong post log trace when you use like the above.. Also try getApplicationContext().findviewby...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are NOT importing android.R (Eclipse WILL suggest this). You should be importing your package's .R